# How do I write on a latex pdf with my editing pen and edit the latex code whilst keeping what I wrote on the pdf without having it disappearing?

Tags: pdftex

As the title is shown. I'm trying to write with my editing pen on my latex pdf and every time I continue writing latex code, it disappears. Is there anyway to mitigate this?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: LaTeX creates a completely new PDF on each run and doesn't consider the current PDF of the output name at all. So no, this isn't possible in LaTeX. Maybe the application you're using for your edits with the pen could somehow save the edits not inside the PDF but in a separate overlay file or something...

Comment: It should work with `xournalpp`, for example, but I do not think it will be able to automatically react to a chance in the PDF... Hmmm, what an idea for a feature request...

Comment: you should make notes in the latex _source_ not in the generated pdf